# Is there a way in Java to set a value of a variable in one class and be able to access from another one

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

Suppose I have a `RestController` and in my post method, I want to set the value of something globally or something, so that I can access it in another class further down the road without having to pass it down the methods:

Suppose I have:

RestController class

```java
public void postMethod() {
    int x = 10;
    serviceMethod(x);
}
```

Service class

```java
public void serviceMethod(int x) {
    componentMethod(x);
}
```

Helper class

```java
public void componentMethod(int x) {
    if(x==10) {
        log.info("YES");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to directly somehow access the value of `x` instead of passing it down every method?

Comment: If the value is only for the duration of the current request, then you could store the value in a `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: I am not sure why do you need it but as mentioned above you store it in ThreadLocal, but only in the case when you are sure that the whole flow is executed in the same thread

Comment: I need it because I do not want to keep passing a variable to every method. The method where I need the variable is further down the call. So when I set it in the conroller, I do not want to keep doing service.a(x) -> component.b(x) -> helper.a(x) -> Helper { a(x) { if(x) { log.info("YES") } } }

Answer (score 0):

Use `ThreadLocal` but please do note that `ThreadLocal` should only be used when you are sure that the flow of the program is executed in the same thread and this is why they call it ThreadLocal.

A tip for you is that when you are using `ThreadLocal`, never write a wrapper over it as each and every developer in the team who wants to use the variable must know it is `ThreadLocal`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You can define the variable in the global scope and create the instance of that class in another class. And using that instance you can access the variable in another class.

For eg.

```
class RestController {
    int x = 10;
}

class Service {
    RestController rs = new RestController();
    int x = rs.x;
    componentMethod(x);
}
```

But if your entire operations/program is being executed in the same thread then consider using `ThreadLocal`. Store the value in `ThreadLocal` and you can use it within the same thread.

Comment: Yes, that is when you already know the value and it is initialized before the system is running. I need to set it when the controller gets hit, initialize the variable there and then used later on.

Comment: You can initialize the controller based on certain conditions by defining them. But in that condition also the flow will be the same as I answered above. If this answer is not what you are looking for, then please elaborate your use case a bit.